# Python 3.4 - XML Parse - IndexError: List Index Out of Range - How do I find range of XML?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-3.4

Okay guys, I'm new to parsing XML and Python, and am trying to get this to work. If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. If you can help me (educate me) on how to figure it out for myself, that would be even better!

I am having trouble trying to figure out the range to reference for an XML document as I can't find any documentation on it. Here is my code and I'll include the entire Traceback after.

```
#import library to do http requests:
import urllib.request

#import easy to use xml parser called minidom:
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
#all these imports are standard on most modern python implementations

#download the file:
file = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/CompendiumSearch.asmx/KeywordSearch?Keywords=healing%20%word&nameOnly=True&tab=')
#convert to string:
data = file.read()
#close file because we dont need it anymore:
file.close()
#parse the xml you downloaded
dom = parseString(data)
#retrieve the first xml tag (<tag>data</tag>) that the parser finds with name tagName:
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('Data.Results.Power.ID')[0].toxml()
#strip off the tag (<tag>data</tag>  --->   data):
xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<id>','').replace('</id>','')
#print out the xml tag and data in this format: <tag>data</tag>
print(xmlTag)
#just print the data
print(xmlData)
```

Traceback

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/mint/PycharmProjects/DnD_Project/Power_Name.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mint/PycharmProjects/DnD_Project/Power_Name.py", line 14, in <module>
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].toxml()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

```
print len( dom.getElementsByTagName('id') )
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
ids = dom.getElementsByTagName('id')

if len( ids ) > 0 :
     xmlTag = ids[0].toxml()
     # rest of code
```

---

**EDIT:** I add example because I saw in other comment tha you don't know how to use it

BTW: I add some comment in code about file/connection

```
import urllib.request

from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

# create connection to data/file on server
connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/CompendiumSearch.asmx/KeywordSearch?Keywords=healing%20%word&nameOnly=True&tab=')

# read from server as string (not "convert" to string):
data = connection.read()

#close connection because we dont need it anymore:
connection.close()

dom = parseString(data)

# get tags from dom
ids = dom.getElementsByTagName('Data.Results.Power.ID')

# check if there are any data
if len( ids ) > 0 :
    xmlTag = ids[0].toxml()
    xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<id>','').replace('</id>','')
    print(xmlTag)
    print(xmlData)
else:
    print("Sorry, there was no data")
```

or you can use `for` loop if there is more tags

```
dom = parseString(data)

# get tags from dom
ids = dom.getElementsByTagName('Data.Results.Power.ID')

# get all tags - one by one
for one_tag in ids:
    xmlTag = one_tag.toxml()
    xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<id>','').replace('</id>','')
    print(xmlTag)
    print(xmlData)
```

BTW:

- `getElementsByTagName()` expects tagname `ID` - not path `Data.Results.Power.ID`
- tagname is `ID` so you have to replace `<ID>` not `<id>`
- for this tag you can event use `one_tag.firstChild.nodeValue` in place of `xmlTag.replace`

.

```
dom = parseString(data)

# get tags from dom
ids = dom.getElementsByTagName('ID') # tagname

# get all tags - one by one
for one_tag in ids:
    xmlTag = one_tag.toxml()
    #xmlData = xmlTag.replace('<ID>','').replace('</ID>','')
    xmlData = one_tag.firstChild.nodeValue
    print(xmlTag)
    print(xmlData)
```

Comment: Replace the 
    print(xmlData)

with 
    

print len(dom.getElementsByTagName('id'))

or do I replace

    print(xmlTag)

with that?



I did that, and I still get the list index out of range based off of line 14

    xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].toxml()

Comment: It only show you how long list you got. Use this information as you wish.

Comment: I add more info in answer.

Comment: Where would I put those in the code so that it won't error on me? I am completely new to them and put them where I thought I should, but it isn't helping. It looks like it should, but I fear that I am just being dense and putting it in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the built in xml library in a while, but it's covered in Mark Pilgrim's great [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/) book.

-- I see as I'm typing this that your question has already been answered but since you mention being new to Python I think you will find the text useful for xml parsing and as an excellent introduction to the language.

If you would like to try another approach to parsing xml and html, I highly recommend [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: The previous solution appeared to work, but didn't actually complete the action. It still provides the IndexError and I can't figure out where to put his code. I have been trying another one that I found elsewhere, and it is kinda working. 

I was trying to get lxml to install into my Linux Mint but it seems to not be working correctly.

Comment: xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('Data.Results.Power.ID')[0] .Check to make sure that you actually have some element before running .toxml(), ie len(xmlTag)

Comment: How would I check to make sure I actually have the element? Is that where I would put the len code that was previously posted?

I am working through the XML tutorial from the Dive Into Python book and finding it extremely educational. Thanks!

Comment: furas gave you the answer. After trying to get the elements with getElementByTagName you check if there's anything there. len() returns the length of a list, dictionary, etc. If the len is 0 then nothing was found based on your criteria.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know where to put the len() statement. Wherever I seem to put it, it brings up the indexerror result. Can you help me by explaining exactly where in the code might help? I've tried putting it directly after where the xmlTag is def at and it doesn't work, the end of the code snippet and it doesn't work.

Comment: I added full example in my answer how to use `len()`.